# What does the following statement mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning, word-in-context

**"There's no city on God's green earth that rocks harder than Chicago."**

Is the statement pertaining to the rich rock culture in chicago, or as in the party scene?

Comment: 'Chicago' is a proper noun so should start with a capital letter.

Comment: I heard this statement in a TV show monologue.

Comment: Be a lamb, would you and educate me on this colloquial?

Comment: I believe it's this 'Rock hard: to render all viewers speechless at one's excellence, ability, or fame.' _The vintage vinyl of Bad Company that my dad gave me rocks hard._ - I don't normally use Urban Dictionary but in this case I can say I agree with this definition.

Comment: I'm still getting no where with this definition. I'm sorry but could you please elaborate a little?

Comment: @RoboVgina In future please include the sources of any quotes or examples in the question itself. It would be better if you specified the exact TV show "A TV show monologue" does not provide proper credit, nor does it help in finding additional context.

Comment: The actual meaning, expressed in fewer words, is 'Chicago is very wonderful!'

Comment: As Fumblefingers said, "rocks hard" used in this kind of slangy imprecise way could mean "There's a lot of rock and roll" or "A lot of fun parties" or even just "Is a great place".  The language just isn't more precise than that.  It implies that the speaker likes Chicago, but not much else.  Could you accept a non-answer along those lines?